# How to iterate over values and create a list of people matching the criteria

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I am new to Python and I was trying to create a loop which would create two lists of people based on the condition. My Dataframe has three columns:

**controln**  **donated**   **amount_donated**

controln is the ID of a person, donated means whether a person donated money or not

I'd like to have a list of people who donated more than $1 and another one which checks if they donated more than $5.
I tried making a loop :

```
above5=[]
above1=[]

for a,c in val1.iterrows():
    a= val1['controln']
    b = val1['donated']
    c= val1['amount_donated']
    for item in c:
        if item >= 5 : 
          above5.append(a)
        if 5> item >= 1 :
            above1.append(a)
        else:
            print('No match')
print('Done')
```

However it does not work as it creates a list of series with all the IDs and not those meeting the conditions.
I tried also with `above1.append((a,c))` but that also doesn't work.

Could anyone advise me on what should be changed?

Comment: can you show the values of val1?

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and expected outputs first?

Comment: is `val1` is a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

You are interpreting a and c given by `iterrows()` incorrectly. The a gives you the index numbers while the c gives you the row. You can get the id from `c[0]`, the donate boolean from `c[1]`, and the amount donated from `c[2]`. Then you can use these and filter them out into appropriate lists using conditional statements. Also in python `if 5> item >= 1` is an invalid conditional syntax.

You are also assigning the whole columns to a, b and c from the dataframe inside the loop by using statements such as `a= val1['controln']`. This is incorrect for your use case and also you should not reassign the `a` that you get from `iterrows()`.

You also don't require a nested for loop `for item in c:` since it does not serve any purpose for your use case.

A correct sample code is as follows:

```
above5=[]
above1=[]

for a,b in df.iterrows():
    id = b[0]
    donate = b[1]
    val = b[2]
    
    if val >= 5: 
     above5.append(id)
    if val >= 1 and val < 5:
     above1.append(id)
    else:
     print('No match')
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

`iterrows()` return the row id and the row [see a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/16813828) .

So you should do something like this:

```py
for a,c in val1.iterrows():
    amount = c['amount_donated']
    if amount >= 5 : 
        above5.append(c['controln'])
    elif amount >= 1 :
        above1.append(c['controln'])
    else:
        print('No match')
print('Done')
```

When you write:
`a = val1['controln']` and appending a to the list, you actually appending the entire column.